# Akeeba backup restore

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am facing error while restoring -

AJAX error:

error(undefined)
Raw Data:

After pressing "Next" on DB restore page. It is in cloud site.

Previously it was working after php 7.2 it was occurring.

I can sort out this problem by commenting out "maxtime". Is it server issue or is there way to avoid it?

Comment: Is it a Joomla 2.5? Then forget that on PHP 7.2. It will not run even if the restore finishes...

Comment: you might temporarily remove your .htaccess and try the restore.  There are many commands within the .htaccess that can cause that error.